# Yii2- unable to redirect from one view to another with dataprovider

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, redirect, yii2

I have a view in which I have a `a` tag button. On the click of the button a an `ajax` request is sent to the given `action view controller` and in that `action view` some values are saved in the database. After that I am redirecting the view to another view.

**What I have done?**

**My View**

```
<a href="<?= URL::toRoute(['ogpheader/viewsetpdf', 'id'=>$model->id])?>"  name="redirect" class="btn btn-primary" id="myid">Set PDF</a>
//this is the a tag button
```

**Ajax call in same view**

```
<?php
$url = Url::toRoute(['/ogpheader/viewsetpdf','id'=>$model->id]);
$script = <<< JS
$(document).ready(function () {      

$('#myid').on('click',function(e) {
e.preventDefault();    
 var strValue = "";        
    $('input[name="selection[]"]:checked').each(function() {

    if(strValue!="")
        {
        strValue = strValue + " , " + this.value;

        }
    else 
       strValue = this.value;     

});
    //alert(strValue);
$.ajax({
     url: '$url',
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: {data:strValue},         
     success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      },
     }); 
    }) 
  });
  JS;
  $this->registerJs($script, static::POS_END);
  ?>
```

**My action Controller**

```
if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax && Yii::$app->request->post())
    {
        $data = explode(',',$_POST['data']);

        foreach($data as $value)
        {
            $m = new Ogpdetail;
            $m -> load(Yii::$app->request->post());
            $m->ogp_id = $ogp_id;
            $m->created_at = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
            $m->meter_id = $value;
            $m->meter_serial = \common\models\Meters::idTomsn($value);

            if($m->save())
            {
                $model->status = Ogpheader::$status_titles[1];
                $model->update();
                //echo "All data is saved";
                //exit();
            }
            else{
                $this->renderAjax('viewcreated');
            }
        }

        //print_r($data);
    }
    else{
        $this->renderAjax('viewcreated');
    }
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT  ogpd.`meter_serial` AS 'Meter_Serial_Number', IFNULL(ogpd.`remarks`,'') AS 'Remarks' FROM `ogp_detail` ogpd
                        INNER JOIN `ogp_header` ogph ON ogpd.`ogp_id` = ogph.`id`";

    $count = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ogpd.`meter_serial`) FROM `ogp_detail` ogpd
                         INNER JOIN `ogp_header` ogph ON ogpd.`ogp_id` = ogph.`id`")->queryScalar();

    $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
        'sql' => $query,
        'totalCount' => $count,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 5,
        ],
    ]);

    return $this->redirect('viewsetpdf',[
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        'id' => $model->id
    ]);
```

When i click on my `Set PDF` button I am getting `Not Found (#404)`. While all the records are saved into my desired tables.

Also the `URL` is `http://localhost:225/inventory-web/backend/web/ogpheader/viewcreated/viewsetpdf` but it should be `http://localhost:225/inventory-web/backend/web/ogpheader/viewsetpdf`

I don't know what is the problem and I am stuck to it.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating a Route, not a URL. Try replacing this:

```
<a href="<?= URL::toRoute(['ogpheader/viewsetpdf', 'id'=>$model->id])?>"  name="redirect" class="btn btn-primary" id="myid">Set PDF</a>
```

With this:

```
Html::a('Set PDF', ['ogpheader/viewsetpdf', 'id'=>$model->id], ['id' => 'myid', 'name'=>'redirect', 'class'='btn btn-primary'])
```

Comment: `Html::a('Set PDF', ['ogpheader/viewsetpdf', 'id'=>$model->id], ['id' => 'myid', 'name'=>'redirect', 'class'='btn btn-primary'])` is viewing as it is in my view

Comment: I do not understand what you mean

Comment: I missed the `<?` in start and end now the updated tag is `<? Html::a('Set PDF',['ogpheader/viewsetpdf','','id'=>$model->id],['id'=>'myid','name'=>'redirect','class'=>'btn btn-primary'])?>` But the button is not visible instead `$model->id], ['id' => 'myid', 'name'=>'redirect', 'class'=>'btn btn-primary'])?>` is appearing as a text

Comment: Use `<?= ... ?>` or `<?php echo ... ?>`

Comment: again i missed `=` with `<?` now the button is visible but the result is again same I am getting wrong URL `...../ogpheader/viewcreated/viewsetpdf`